# Is there an option to disable a plugin in babel when using a preset?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am using [babel](http://babeljs.io) with [babel-preset-es2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/).

Is there a way to disable a specific plugin from within the 'package.json' configuration to avoid having to fork this preset just to remove one plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Babel team is [currently not interested in supporting presets that way](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T3016):

> Right now the intention of the preset is to allow people to use it without customization - if you want to modify it then you'll have to just define plugins yourself or make your own preset.